# Not less than operator

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake how do I use a not less than operator?

If I want to return all rows that are not less than a value? Not sure if I want to use >=  and tried !< but doesnt work

Thank

Comment: Please add your actual query, along with some sample data.

Comment: Updated @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: you were right with `>=` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There no "not less than" [operator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-comparison.html), but it's logically the same as "greater than or equal to":

```
a >= b
```

or, if you want to express "not less than" as SQL:

```
not (a < b)
```